# Dynamic Element created inside a div must be clicked

Tags: dynamic, click, element, bind, any

I need get the id of my dynamic created element  inside a div.
I'm looking for a way to get it's id by clicking it.
Example:

```
$("#div").on("click", '*', function () {
    alert($(this).id);
});
```

The element can be an image, link, button, etc...
I need to dynamic bind click to it, and get the id when gets clicked.

I use append to add sub elements to div.

```
$("#div").append(element);
```

Elements are right shown, but i can't retrive the ids.

Is there anyway to get it?

Example in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/StTvn

Comment: post the code that generates `element` and the markup, or better create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/StTvn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/StTvn/2/

changed the listener selector and it works

```
     $("#myDiv").on("click", "*", function () {
     txt = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(txt);
 });
```

as a side note, id that start with a number are not valid html - you might want to change the way you generate them like this:

```
el.id=  "img" + i.toString();
```

Comment: This worked with $("#elementid") but with a different selector like $(".class#id .class") it wasn't working. Changed to ids. Thanx.